# not able to connect to server on web, but working perfectly on localhost centos

Tags: web-server, centos6

I have been trying to setup my centos web server and I succeeded last week in doing so.

From the last week the server was running perfectly, but when today I restarted the server, for some reasons, I am not able to connect to it on web, but server is running perfectly on localhost interface.

I have checked the firewall (iptables) and its perfectly allowing both ways communication for port 80 and 443 on tcp protocol. My router is also forwarding port 80 and 443 to my server. Moreover, ping command is working fine.

please check www.qdesk.in

I have checked the httpd configuration file and everything seems ok in it.

If someone has an idea on what could be the possible flaw..

Answer (score 0):

You can try a portscan using "nmap". If port 80 is open from your external client, then you can narrow the problem down to your web server configuration.

try:
'nmap -A HOSTNAME' and check if port 80 and 443 are open.